# Deploy IdentityServer on 3 different server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

We have developed one web site([www.lightman.com](http://www.lightman.com)) with Web API and to protect our API we developed IdentityServer4 app to provide access_token just to authorize the API request.
When ever Client request the API , we just add JWT "access_token" in request header and everything looks good.

Now we deploy our apps in 3 different server including IdentityServer. but not sure how to handle the JWT "access_token" across all 3 servers since we are not sure which server provide the token and which server the API call will go for Authorization .

Please guide on this scenario

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [signing key](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/startup.html#key-material) using [AddSigningCredential], this key will be shared between all instances you deployed:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(...).AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(bytes, "password")
```

Read more on [deployment docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/deployment.html)

Comment: Thanks and one more questions it will resolve when I deploy my web and API also in multiple instance . correct me if im wrong ?